# What visa does a US-born baby need?

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, children

I was born in the UK and moved to the US a few years ago to be with my husband. I'm now moving back and will be accompanied by my minor (8 months old) child. They'll be traveling on a US passport. What, if any, visa will my child need to remain in the UK with me permanently?

Answer (score 5):

You were born in the UK.  I assume you you are a British citizen, because you make no mention of your own visa.  Because you were born in the UK, you are a British citizen "otherwise than by descent," and your child is therefore also a British citizen (by descent, however).  In that case, your child obviously does not need a visa, but it will probably be simplest to apply for a UK passport for your child before you move to the UK.

Even if you do not apply for a British passport for your child, your child does not need a visa to enter the UK because of his or her British citizenship, and does not need a visa to board a plane to the UK because US citizens do not require visas to enter the UK.

(The consequence of your child being a British citizen "by descent" is that any children of your child who are born outside the UK will not be British citizens unless the other parent is a British citizen otherwise than by descent.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes! I am a British citizen. I'll be flying on my British passport. So I should forgo apply for an American passport for my daughter and apply, instead for a British one? Is this a lengthy process? My standing in my current residence is somewhat shaky so I'm looking for the quickest possible departure.

Comment: @J.Doe Your daughter needs a US passport to enter the US. In other words, she should have both. The UK doesn't have a similar requirement, however. I do not know which application takes longer, nor do I even know how long either application is likely to take for a first-time passport for an infant. If you arrive without a UK passport, I suppose you will be okay if you have your daughter's birth certificate showing that you are her mother, assuming your UK passport shows that you were born in the UK. If time is truly critical, you can apply for both and leave as soon as the first is available.